# How to change <li> value in an <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

I want to change a specific value of li which doesn't have any id, how can I access this li and change it to another value.
in the following code, I want to change "Edit as Drop" to just "Edit" using jquery or javascript.

```
<ul class="tabs--primary nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="/packages/50411" data-drupal-link-system-path="packages/50411" class="is-active">View<span class="visually-hidden">(active tab)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/packages/50411/edit" data-drupal-link-system-path="packages/50411/edit">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="/packages/50411/delete" data-drupal-link-system-path="packages/50411/delete">Delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="/packages/50411/edit/enrollment_drop_mode" data-drupal-link-system-path="packages/50411/edit/enrollment_drop_mode">Edit as Drop</a></li>
    <li><a href="/devel/packages/50411" data-drupal-link-system-path="devel/packages/50411">Devel</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using jQuery's [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector which *selects all elements that contain the specified text*:

```js
$('ul li a:contains(Edit as Drop)').text('Edit');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs--primary nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="/packages/50411" data-drupal-link-system-path="packages/50411" class="is-active">View<span class="visually-hidden">(active tab)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/packages/50411/edit" data-drupal-link-system-path="packages/50411/edit">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="/packages/50411/delete" data-drupal-link-system-path="packages/50411/delete">Delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="/packages/50411/edit/enrollment_drop_mode" data-drupal-link-system-path="packages/50411/edit/enrollment_drop_mode">Edit as Drop</a></li>
    <li><a href="/devel/packages/50411" data-drupal-link-system-path="devel/packages/50411">Devel</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child() for this problem, something like this:

```
$( ".nav-tabs li:nth-child(4) a" ).html( "Edit" );
```

Answer (score 0):

i can feel the downvotes coming...but why not add an ID and use innerHTML to set the value to another `<a>`